# Glossaries/acronyms list is not ordered properly

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm using packet glossaries and I have the following acronym list:

```
\newacronym{AI}{AI}{Ambient Intelligence} %
\newacronym{CRL}{CRL}{Certificate Revocation List} %
\newacronym{ETSI}{ETSI}{European Telecommunications Standards Institute} %
\newacronym{FI}{FI}{Future Internet} %
\newacronym{PPAN}{\mbox{P-PAN}}{Private Personal Area Network} %
```

The result is

```
P-PAN Private Personal Area Network
AI    Ambient Intelligence
CRL   Certificate Revocation List
ETSI  European Telecommunications Standards Ins-
      titute
FI    Future Internet
```

As you can see the ones that are included in \mbox{} are listed the first without noting that the first letter is a P. How can I make it possible to have it properly ordered? Do I have to change the way I define the acronymn? I have defined it this way because I don't want it to be splitted in two lines.

Thanks

**Edit: MWE**

acronyms.tex

```
\newacronym{AI}{AI}{Ambient Intelligence} %
\newacronym{CRL}{CRL}{Certificate Revocation List} %
\newacronym{ETSI}{ETSI}{European Telecommunications Standards Institute} %
\newacronym{FI}{FI}{Future Internet} %
\newacronym{PPAN}{\mbox{P-PAN}}{Private Personal Area Network} %
```

acro.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{translator}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[acronym, toc, shortcuts, translate=babel]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand{\glspostdescription}{} % Remove page number
\loadglsentries[type=\acronymtype]{acronyms}


\begin{document}

\ac{AI}
\ac{CRL}
\ac{ETSI}
\ac{FI}
\ac{PPAN}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=super, nonumberlist]
\clearpage%


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make the snippet into a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @egreg there you have it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `sort` key:

```
\newacronym[sort=PPAN]{PPAN}{\mbox{P-PAN}}{Private Personal Area Network}
```

Example (I use `\jobname` and `filecontents*` not to clobber my files, use your own method with the `acronyms.tex` file).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-acro}
\newacronym{AI}{AI}{Ambient Intelligence}
\newacronym{CRL}{CRL}{Certificate Revocation List}
\newacronym{ETSI}{ETSI}{European Telecommunications Standards Institute}
\newacronym{FI}{FI}{Future Internet}
\newacronym[sort=PPAN]{PPAN}{\mbox{P-PAN}}{Private Personal Area Network}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{translator}

\usepackage[nomain,acronym, toc, shortcuts, translate=babel]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand{\glspostdescription}{} % Remove page number
\loadglsentries[type=\acronymtype]{\jobname-acro}


\begin{document}

\ac{AI}
\ac{CRL}
\ac{ETSI}
\ac{FI}
\ac{PPAN}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=super, nonumberlist]
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh, gee, i really do wish this kind of list would have an easy to use "ragged right" option.

Comment: @barbarabeeton There are ragged styles in `glossary-superragged.sty` and `glossary-longragged.sty`.